# Android app rotating loses back button

Tags: bug, android-app

When viewing a question on the Android app, I am able to tap the back arrow button in the top left corner. However, if I rotate the device then I lose the back arrow and get the usual "hamburger" icon for opening the sidebar menu. Further rotation continues to display the hamburger icon.

> [image]

This seems like a bug - the back arrow should be retained even if the device is rotated.

I have produced this error on a Samsung Galaxy S5.

Comment: Just reproduced on my s5

Comment: Reproduced on LG (G3), adding screenshot as well. :)

Comment: Does it only change the icon, or do you also get menu functionality when you tap the button, rather than going back? Sadly no repro on my Hong Kong HTC e8.

Comment: I've just tried this again, and I can no longer reproduce the error.

Comment: Confirmed not repro'd on SE app v1.0.82 (beta).